# Cloud Run: how do I set check_same_thread=False?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

My project which runs in Cloud Run of Google Cloud Platform (GCP) has generated errors: **SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object was created in thread id 68387105408768 and this is thread id 68386614675200.** for hours before it went back to normal by itself.

Our code is written in Python with flask & no SQLite is involved. Saw suggestions to set `check_same_thread` to `False`. May I know where I can set this in Cloud Run or GCP? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That setting has nothing to do with your runtime environment, but is set during the connection initialization with sqlite (https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#module-functions), so if you claim that you aren't creating an sqlite connection that won't help you much.

That being said, I find it hard to believe that you are getting that error without using sqlite. More likely is that you are using sqlite via some dependency.

Since sqlite3 is part of the standard library of python it might however not be trivial to figure out which dependency uses it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll discuss with my colleague who had initialized the connection about 2 years ago to work on it. Thanks.